# Perforce Setup Issue

Tags: perforce

I've got a Perforce server set up, and installed the P4V client.  I've created a new depot and a new workspace.  Per the documentation, I've mapped the workspace to the depot.  So far so good.

I now have a .SQL script that was created by an external application that I wish to check in for the first time.  I copied the file into my workspace and can see the file in the client's workspace tree window.  Yet when I attempt to mark the file for add, I get a "file(s) not opened on this client" error.  I've tried editing a changelist to include the file, but the changelist editor does not "see" the file.

I've read through the documentation (PDF files), but I just do not see what I'm missing.  I've worked with other RCS software in a commercial setting, but this is my first stab at trying to set up and administer and RCS system up for personal use.

Comment: When you get a solution, please rename your question as a question, for example, something like "How do I map a workspace to a depot in Perforce?"

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is likely to be with the mappings.  This is a reasonably common issue.

Taking your details

```
Workspace root: C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666

File dir under root: C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666\tunnel_files

View mappings:

//tunnel/... //wtansill_localhost_1666/tunnel/...

//tunnel/* //wtansill_localhost_1666/tunnel/*
```

With the details above, the  line

```
//tunnel/... //wtansill_localhost_1666/tunnel/...
```

means that you need to place the files you wish to add into the root of your workspace plus the directory tunnel eg.

C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666\tunnel

rather than

```
C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666\tunnel_files
```

where you seem to have put them.  A way around this is

1. Create the tunnel folder in the correct place (and any subfolders)
2. Remove the final folder from your workspace mapping so

   //tunnel/... //wtansill_localhost_1666/tunnel/...
   becomes
   //tunnel/... //wtansill_localhost_1666/...

this would mean anything under

C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666\tunnel_files

would be mapped to //tunnel/tunnel_files which is I think what you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your filespec includes the directory you have added your file in?

Perhaps you could post your ClientSpec, and the directory in which your file is located?

Answer (score 0):

Workspace root: C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666

File dir under root: C:\Documents and Settings\wtansill\Perforce\wtansill_localhost_1666\tunnel_files

View mappings:

//tunnel/...    //wtansill_localhost_1666/tunnel/...

//tunnel/*  //wtansill_localhost_1666/tunnel/*

It's sort of a moot point though.  The above workspace was the default set up by Perforce when I installed it.  I deleted that workspace and created a new one using the P4V client, retraced my original steps, and now, lo, it works!  Go figure.

Comment: I think the * line override the ... line, so only files in the top directory were mapped?

Comment: Exactly.  Take that second line out.  The first line covers everything that second line maps already.  And you will only be able to add files into that tunnel subdirectory locally, because there is nothing mapped to the root of your workspace.